# retrieve a default preference key

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to retrieve a default value (which is the last value saved)
I am making some changes in the background color of the layout
so before the setContentView 
I put this code in.

`SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("UID",MODE_PRIVATE);
setTheme(preferences.getInt("color",R.style.AppTheme));`

But it won't work, the R.style.Apptheme's background color (which I set in the style.xml) works but I have changed the bg's color with this code

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("UID",MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferences.edit().putInt("color",R.style.red_theme).commit();
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
```

what is the proper way of retrieving the last saved style?

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so post the error log.

Comment: Sorry but didn't properly understood the question. Can you clarify?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have been fixed this already, I just forgot to close this post, it's just that I remove the android:background from the layout xml and it's working :)